# TFS on-premises users

Tags: tfs

I have two questions regarding TFS on-premises:

1. Can I add Microsoft accounts as users? So that one can log in using Visual Studio and not be prompted for username and password when using Team Explorer.
2. Do I need a license for each user that I create on the TFS server that is used for TFS operations in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

1) no, you can only user Microsoft accounts (MSA) with visual studio online. This will not work on premises, as TFS is active directory authenticated and AD does not support MSA.

2) yes, everyone needs a licence, however the stakeholder licence is granted for 'free' if you have TFS 2013.4+. This will not give access to code or test. You would need the Basic CAL for Coders and a Test Professional CAL for Testers.

If you have MSDN then any user with the relevant MSDN gets the correct CAL.

Comment: If I have AD users or just regular users on that machine, how do I associate CALs to those users? Do I need a CAL for each user?

Comment: In settings on TFS you get an allocation page for CAL's. Everyone accessing TFS needs to be assigned a call that turns on our off features. You get 5 basic CAL included and every developer and tester MSDN includes a cal.

Comment: Licensing whitepaper provides every detail incase u need it: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350)